# Nivoslider fade animation not working in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, fade, nivo-slider

I had configured nivoslider banner for

http://my-architect.com.au/index.html

It is set to only show fade effect. I have tested it. It works fine in all browsers except Chrome. Please help me to fix this issue as i could not find any help on internet. I have used this plugin several time before and never had this kind of problem.